# Issues with 2d array indexing python when making game

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I'm attempting to program my own connect four game using Python. I'm trying to sort the circles that I have drawn into a 2d array. However when I try to assign my shape object to the array it gives me an index error. I can't really see an issue with counterrow and countrercolumn, can anyone else? Btw my space class just has an initialiser setting x1, x2, y1, y2, taken, and id

```
from tkinter import *
from space import *

master = Tk();
w = Canvas(master, width = 600, height = 500)
w.pack()

spaceList = []
for i in range(7):
    spaceList.append([0] * 6)
currentmove = 'PLAYER1'
won = False
counterrow = 0
countercolumn = 0

for i in range(0,560,80):
    for j in range(0,480,80):
        w.create_oval(10+i, 10+j, 90+i, 90+j)
        newspace = Space(10+i, 10+j, 90+i, 90+j, False, 'EMPTY')
        spaceList[counterrow][countercolumn] = newspace
        countercolumn = countercolumn + 1
    counterrow = counterrow + 1

while(not won):
    movecol = int(input("Please select a column!"))

def move(column):
    for i in spaceList:
        return 0

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the countercolumn:

```
for i in range(0,560,80):
    # add this:
    countercolumn = 0
    for j in range(0,480,80):
        # omitted
```

Otherwise it becomes seven and larger and you get an overflow.